# How to Copy data from listview in form 1 to listview in form 2

Tags: vb.net, listview

How to do you copy data from listview in form 1 to listview in form 2?

i need help i'm using VB. still a newbie in vb

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

There's the code to use in your Form2 to copy data from ListView1 in Form1 :

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Form1.ListBox1.Items)
```

You should maybe clear the items before it... (`ListBox1.Items.Clear`).

Comment: where do i put the ListView1.Items.Clear?

Comment: Just before `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Form1.ListBox1.Items)`. So it'll clear the items before adding data from the other ListBox. The `AddRange ` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) will add a table of objects (`items As Object()`) after the existing data.